# Job fails during the collect phase due to buffer size limitation?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I get a job failure due to 'cannot grow bufferholder' error while running Spark 2.4.3 and Python 2.7.

When my input data is small, I am able to make everything work smoothly. But when I double my input to a few thousand users (think of a feature generation engine), my job fails. I have tried repartitioning, increasing the cluster size (currently running r4xl 16 workers), but nothing seems to help. From my understanding so far, it seems like there might be a rdd that might be crossing the 2GB limit. But I am unsure what the workaround for this issue might be.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 125.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 125.0 (TID 20649, 10.46.228.23, executor 6): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot grow BufferHolder by size 1040 because the size after growing exceeds size limitation 2147483632
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.BufferHolder.grow(BufferHolder.java:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.grow(UnsafeWriter.java:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.writeAlignedBytes(UnsafeWriter.java:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.write(UnsafeWriter.java:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$generateResultProjection$1.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$generateResultProjection$1.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.next(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.next(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:149)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1495)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have explained the issue and solution aswell. Collect brings all the data to main memmory which is limited. You should repartition (which you are doing) and save all these files to some temp folder. Load each files to dataframe one by one, collect their data, unpersist them once the computations are done.

Comment: So I try doing this, but at some point, even 100.000 partitions don't save the job. Are there any other ways to get around this limitation?

Comment: Try to get the size estimate (I was calculating with number rows*number of column/HARD LIMIT). I was able to read 2.7 GB file (with collect method).